# How to check for a sublist in a list of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Let's say I have this code:

```
lst1 = [['1','g','8','c','p'],['lion','tiger','bear','oh','my'],['true','false','maybe','g','8']]
lst2 = ['g','8']
```

How would I check if lst2 is in lst1?

Comment: The naive solution would be `any(all(i in x for i in lst2) for x in lst1)`.  This wouldn't handle quantity, just existence however. (This assumes you want to check if the elements of `lst2` are contained within a sublist of `lst1`)

Comment: Do you mean if any of the sublists of `lst1` contain the sequence `'g', '8'`?

Comment: `lst2 in lst1`, if that is really what you're asking. I'm guessing it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you can just use `set` and `any`:

```
any(set(lst2) <= set(x) for x in lst1)
```

where `set(lst2) <= set(x)` checks if `lst2` is sublist of `x`.